# Hide column in sharepoint 2013 based on the value from another column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a SharePoint 2013 list, and I want to hide certain columns based on a users selection from a drop down list in another column in the same list.  Anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using the below Sample jquery script
when the dropdown selection changed, the columns visibility change
replace **"col1** and **"col2"** with you columns 
and the **"dropdown column name"** with your dropdown column , and of course 
**dropdown option 1** & **dropdown option 2** with the selection values

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type=text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

       // col1 is hidden by default , col2 is visible 
      $('nobr:contains("col1")').closest('tr').hide();

      // Show/hide columns based on Drop Down Selection

      // hide col2 and show col1 when selecting "dropdown option 1"
      $("select[title='dropdown column name']").change(function() {
      if ($("select[title='dropdown column name']").val() == "dropdown option 1") {
               $('nobr:contains("col2")').closest('tr').hide();
               $('nobr:contains("col1")').closest('tr').show();
           } 
      // hide col1 and show col2 when selecting "dropdown option 2"
      else if($("select[title='dropdown column name']").val() == "dropdown option 2"){
             $('nobr:contains("col1")').closest('tr').hide();
             $('nobr:contains("col2")').closest('tr').show();
          }
     });
});
</script>
```